# How to get input file name as column within Apache Drill query

Tags: hive, apache-drill

I want to know the filename of the file I am querying from using Apache Drill. I know, we can query INPUT__FILE__NAME in Hive but could not find any similar thing in Apache Drill.

Answer (score 2):

This is a new feature that was merged recently. I think it should be available in the 1.7 release.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3474